# Making column that has interval data type from a column of string in BIG QUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sqldatatypes

I am struggling to figure out how to convert my column of string to interval data type. But my problem is that I only want the HOURS to SECONDS portion of it to be reflected on the table not the "Y-M D H:M:S". I needed it to be able to create my visualization properly in tableau. How do I just get the "H:M:S" to reflect on the table?

Here is my code with annotations it did give me the interval but I can't figure out how to just get the hours to seconds:

/*updating a data type from string to interval*/

/*STEP 1- changing the column name to dump it later*/
ALTER TABLE
`scenic-arc-373908.Cyclistic_Data.04_2022`
RENAME COLUMN ride_length TO ride_length_to_dump

/*STEP 2- add a new column name with the original name and required data type*/
ALTER TABLE `scenic-arc-373908.Cyclistic_Data.04_2022`
ADD COLUMN ride_length INTERVAL

/*STEP 3- drop the new column because I have to set the interval right*/
ALTER TABLE `scenic-arc-373908.Cyclistic_Data.04_2022`
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS ride_length

/*STEP 4- updating the table to get all the info from ride_length_to_dump into ride_length*/
UPDATE
`scenic-arc-373908.Cyclistic_Data.04_2022`
SET ride_length = CAST(ride_length_to_dump AS INTERVAL 'H')
WHERE ride_length_to_dump IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

import datetime

## Example input string representing time interval

input_str = "3 days 12:30:45"

## Parse the string and extract time portion

time_portion = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_str, "%d days %H:%M:%S").time()

print(time_portion)

12:30:45

sql :

SELECT SUBSTRING(time_interval_column, CHARINDEX(' ', time_interval_column) + 1, LEN(time_interval_column))
FROM your_table_name;

note:
This SQL query will extract the time portion from your string column. Adjust the query as per your database system and column names.

Comment: Hi Durgesh, would this update it on the table that I will extract to make the visualization?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract)

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DATETIME("2022-02-05 23:15:00")) as hour;

/*------------------*
 | hour             |
 +------------------+
 | 15               |
 *------------------*/
```

Comment: but for this I would have to enter the value in each column and the issue is that I have 37k values that need to just read for time without data